# Error: The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the RecordType.Name field

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to prevent Recordtype from being changed for Account. when I use ISCHANGED(   RecordType.Name   ) in validation rule, the following error appears:

Error: The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the RecordType.Name field.
I have tried using different fields with the same error. I noted that the record type is another object. if this is the reason why I cannot, is there a suggestion as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reference the lookup field on the object itself, rather then indexing across the relationship field. In this case, that would be `RecordTypeId`.

`ISCHANGED()` cannot reference fields on other objects; as you note, the Record Type is itself another object that's joined to the record via the `RecordTypeId` lookup field.